# Javascript: Sorting Objects (not arrays) in descending

Tags: javascript, sorting, object

I know objects are by default sorted out in ascending order or the way we will insert but I need the best way to sort the object in descending order. Ex:

```
Input x = {
  a: {},
  b: {},
  c: {},
  d: {}
}

Output: x = {
  d: {},
  c: {},
  b: {},
  a: {}
}
```

I tried the below solution, It works but is it a good practice or can I get anything better on this?

```
x= Object.keys(x).sort().reverse().reduce((obj, key) => {
    obj[key] = x[key]
    return obj
}, {})
```

Comment: Object properties don't have a guaranteed order, like array elements do.

Comment: yeah, I know but do we have a better way to sort this? or the above solution is fine?

Comment: Maybe sort them first: `Object.keys(x).sort((a, b) => b.localeCompare(a)).reduce()`

Comment: You can't reliably sort something that doesn't have a guaranteed order.  Use arrays if you need them sorted!

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn Good catch, but In my case object is already in ascending order that's y I didn't use sort(). Anyway thanks.

Comment: If all your `keys` are not numeric, you can try the upcoming [Object.fromEntries()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries) like `Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(x).reverse())`

Comment: @James—since ECMAScript 2017 they do, see the  abstract operation [*OrdinaryOwnPropertyKeys*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/10.0/#sec-ordinaryownpropertykeys) which is used by various methods when accessing property names. However not all implementations in use may be compliant.

Comment: @James That is no longer true. Javascript objects **do** have guaranteed order, assuming your key names aren't positive integer values. I would never recommend using an object for anything reliant on order, but the notion that "object properties don't have a guaranteed order" is misinformation.

Comment: I should clarify that even with positive integer key names, objects still have guaranteed order. Though in that case, "guaranteed order" != "creation order".

Comment: @Naren Use a `Map` to guarantee order while using `.entries()` methods to preserve key/value pairs. See my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56997249/2813224)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Array.sort method. 
I believe this will only sort on the first level depth

```
 const list = 
 { 
   a: "4",
   c: "2",
   b: "3",
   d: "1"
 }
 const sortedList = {};
 Object.keys(list).sort().reverse().forEach(function(key) {
  sortedList[key] = list[key];
 });
```

Comment: See the comment on zer00ne's answer above.

Answer (score 1):

Use a Map to guarantee order while using `Object.entries()` method to preserve key/value pairs.

- Get an array of arrays from `Object.entries()`
- `.reverse()` it
- Convert it into a Map (**`Map()` guarantees order** according to how it was entered)
- Use [Object.fromEntries()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries) on Map to return an object.

```js
let obj = {a:{}, b:{}, c:{}, d:{}};
let rev = new Map(Object.entries(obj).reverse());
let ent = Object.fromEntries(rev);
console.log(ent);
```

See [compatibility table](https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es2016plus/#test-Asynchronous_Iterators) for `Object.fromEntries()`

Comment: You can't enforce a particular sorting in general. Since ECMAScript 2017, the order is positive integer keys in ascending numeric order, then strings that aren't symbols in insertion order, then symbols in insertion order. So you can't order integer keys in descending order and can't mix integers, strings and symbols. The abstract operation [*OrdinaryOwnPropertyKeys*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/10.0/#sec-ordinaryownpropertykeys) is used by everything that gets keys.

Comment: I thought `Object.entries()` returns `[[key, value], [ley, value],...]` in this case key turns into a string. And `Map()` accepts anything as a key in insertion order. Oh, the `.sort()` is useless then? Will update.