# Order object based in another one in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Goal: to create an object with an specific order defined by an object, but only when the fields exists on the input data.

What I have and done:

This object defines the order:

```
const fieldsOrder = {
  token: undefined,
  agentID: undefined,
  agentSequence: undefined,
  allOptions: undefined
}
```

This is the body request that I need to sort:

```
const request = {
  allOptions: false,
  agentSequence: 6,
  agentID: 123,
  token: 'test'
}
```

The sorted object is `sortedObject`

```
const sortedObject = Object.assign(fieldsOrder, request);
console.log(sortedObject);

{
  agentID: 123,
  agentSequence: 6,
  allOptions: false,
  token: 'test'
}
```

Not working.

I was trying what I found here: [Changing the order of the Object keys....](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6959817/changing-the-order-of-the-object-keys)

Here are some tests:

```js
// This object defines de order:

const fieldsOrder = {
  token: undefined,
  agentID: undefined,
  agentSequence: undefined,
  allOptions: undefined
}

// 1st case: all fields
// This is the body request that I need to sort:
const request = {
  allOptions: true,
  agentSequence: 6,
  agentID: 123,
  token: 'test',
}

// The sorted object is `sortedRequest`

const sortedRequest = Object.assign(fieldsOrder, request);

// WRONG order...
console.log(sortedRequest); 

/*
I expected this order:
{
  token: 'test'
    agentID: 123,
  agentSequence: 6,
  allOptions: false
}
*/

/*************************************/

// 2nd case: some fields

const requestShort = {
  allOptions: true,
  agentID: 123,
  token: 'test',
}

const sortedRequest2 = Object.assign(fieldsOrder, requestShort);

// WRONG order...
console.log(sortedRequest2); 

/*
I expected this order:
{
  token: 'test'
    agentID: 123,
  allOptions: false
}
*/
```

How could I fix it? I need to order the `request` by `fieldsOrder` but only using the fields on the `request`object.

Comment: `I need to order the request by fieldsOrder`, why?

Comment: I will send that object to an stupid API (SOAP, badly designed) that needs a certain order or it fails.

Comment: You could just create a different object with the keys in the correct order and just set their values to the values from the out of order object. It’s not a fancy solution but it will work. You can even put it in a function to reuse it.

Comment: The order of fields have only recently become deterministic, if you run code that depends on field order on an old machine or in an old browser, then it will fail randomly.

Comment: Keep in mind that objects are not a good option if you need an ordered collection of items. The ideal would be either an array or a Map, where the order is guaranteed. See more: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5525820/3496534

Comment: But that will be hard with the 2nd case that I put in the fiddle. The request will not always have the same fields, but in case thos fields exists, they need a specific order

Comment: @RuanMartinelli I need to send an object, and what I have as input is an object too. I tried to define the sort template as an array but I have some problems with indexes (Eslinter was giving me errors)

Comment: So have an array of keys, loop over it. If the key exists add it to a new object. Weird thing is object order was really never guaranteed so a bit weird order would matter.

Comment: There are several other answers on that question besides the one mentioning `Object.assign`... do any of those work?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sort JavaScript object by key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5467129/sort-javascript-object-by-key)

Comment: Thanks to everyone, I'm reading each answer and comment now.

Comment: Similar question you can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56996782/javascript-sorting-objects-not-arrays-in-descending)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
const keys = ["token", "agentID", "agentSequence", "allOptions"]

function sortRequest(request) {
  return keys.reduce((sortedRequest, key) => {
    if (key in request) sortedRequest[key] = request[key]
    return sortedRequest
  }, {})
}


console.log(sortRequest({
  allOptions: false,
  agentSequence: 6,
  agentID: 123,
  token: 'test'
}))
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `Object#entries` to get an array of key-value tuples, then sort that array based on the index of each key in the "targetOrder" object, then turn those key-value tuples back into an object using `Object#fromEntries`. However the order of fields have only recently become deterministic, if you run code that depends on field order on an old machine or in an old browser, then it will fail randomly.

```js
const targetOrder = Object.keys({
  token: undefined,
  agentID: undefined,
  agentSequence: undefined,
  allOptions: undefined
});

const req = {
  allOptions: true,
  agentSequence: 6,
  agentID: 123,
  token: 'test',
}

const orderedReq = Object.fromEntries(
  Object.entries(req)
    .sort(([k1], [k2]) =>
      targetOrder.indexOf(k1) - targetOrder.indexOf(k2)
    ),
);

console.log(orderedReq);
```

Comment: Hm, nice, it seemds that JSfiddle is sorting the output console.log, jesus, spend hours looking the jsfiddle console, and not the Chrome console.

Comment: @pmiranda I was thinking that might have been the case, but since I'm not sure what system/environment you where on I couldn't be sure.

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate trough the keys of the request object and assign every key that exist in fieldsOrder. After that just simply remove all unset fields.

```
const fieldsOrder = {
  token: undefined,
  agentID: undefined,
  agentSequence: undefined,
  allOptions: undefined
}

const request = {
  allOptions: false,
  agentSequence: 6,
  agentID: 123,
  token: 'test'
}

Object.keys(request)
      .filter(key => key in fieldsOrder)
      .forEach(key => fieldsOrder[key] = request[key])
Object.keys(fieldsOrder)
      .filter(key => fieldsOrder[key] === undefined)
      .forEach(key => delete fieldsOrder[key])
```

With this solution you do not need to modify your existing objects or creating any string array.

Answer (score 0):

So have an array of keys and loop over it to make a new object.

```js
var fields = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz'];

var data1 = {
  baz: 456,
  foo: 123
};

var data2 = {
  baz: 987,
  foo: 765,
  bar: undefined
};

// only returned if has value
function test1(data) {
  return fields.reduce((o, k) => {
    if (data[k] !== undefined) o[k] = data[k];
    return o;
  }, {});
}

// return everything
function test2(data) {
  return fields.reduce((o, k) => (o[k] = data[k], o), {});
}

// return if it has the key
function test3(data) {
  return fields.reduce((o, k) => {
    if (k in data) {
      o[k] = data2[k];
    }
    return o;
  }, {});
}

console.group('test1')
console.log(test1(data1));
console.log(test1(data2));
console.groupEnd('test1')

console.group('test2')
console.log(test2(data1));
console.log(test2(data2));
console.groupEnd('test2')

console.group('test3')
console.log(test3(data1));
console.log(test3(data2));
console.groupEnd('test3')
```

Comment: This would fail if `undefined` is a valid value for a required field.

Comment: Yes, some data could be: `data = { id: 1, token: null, status: false, name: undefined, code: '' }`

Comment: @Olian04 I made an assumption it was just items that are defined. Lack of data of what values could be means I HAVE TO GUESS. Hence why these details need to be given. So if it can be undefined, remove the check. I altered it to remove the undefined check